# how to pass id using a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to give an id (each time different id) to attach value obtained in html attribute. I am a bit confused with it. help needed. below is my code for JavaScript and HTML.

```js
$("#id").text(res); // conventional way
var i = 0;      
  $(#i).text(res); // this is what i need :/
```

```html
<p>last message: <var id="0">name</var> </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("#" + i).text(res);
```

jQuery selectors are purely strings that get parsed afterwards by the framework itself. So you can easily form a string with the id selector `#` and your variable that contains the integer. There is no magic here whatsoever.